# Find location of matched pattern

Tags: search

I am using `matchadd()` to match some text in a line.  Using Vim script, how can I jump to the matched text?  Or, instead, how can I get the column number of the start of the match?

Motivation: I have one or more pieces of known text at known locations on a line and I want to jump from one to the next so they can be amended.  However as soon as the user amends something, the locations become out of date.  So instead of using locations and `matchaddpos()` I'm using patterns and `matchadd()`.

I tried setting marks at the start when the locations are known, but marks only auto-update when the line number changes, not the column number.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your use case but if you need to move to some text defined by a pattern wouldn't it be easier to use [`:h search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29)?

Comment: did you already try `getmatches()`?

Comment: @statox That's what I have ended up doing, but since Vim is keeping track of the text internally, to keep the `matchaddpos()` highlight in the right place, I was wondering whether there's a way to access that internal location information.

Comment: @Mass Yes but it doesn't include any location information.